# Xcode 5 causing internet connectivity issues on Macbook Air

Tags: xcode, debugging, connectivity

If this isn't an appropriate question for SO, let me know and I'll take it down.

While working in Xcode on my MBA, I sometimes encounter a strange problem. It goes something like this:

1. Code, build and test my app on iPhone for a period of time (hours).
2. Save work, unplug iPhone test device, put MBA to sleep by closing lid.
3. Come back later and wake up MBA.
4. Internet on my MBA will not reconnect until I plug iPhone back in and continue to work on app.

The internet problem occurs around 70% of the time, and it seems to only subside once I continue work.

I understand this sounds like a vague and un-researched question, but I have looked and haven't found a solution.

Is this happening for anyone else? Perhaps I should file it as a radar...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are running Maveric OS (v10.9.*). 
 Try resetting [SMC](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964) & [PRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379) with precaution ..